# How to select special date records in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I'm already using a query like below to select records on a special date since I'm storing a sort of date on my table:

```
... WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR((SELECT MAX(date) FROM tblname)) AND
          MONTH(date) = MONTH((SELECT MAX(date) FROM tblname)) AND
          DAY(date) = DAY((SELECT MAX(date) FROM tblname)) ...
```

but I'm looking for a more simple way to doing this.

What SQL query should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
... WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(SELECT MAX(date) FROM tblname)) ...
```